# Equation numbering - matrix

Tags: equations, numbering, matrices

The following matrix produces an equation number on the line following the matrix, opposed to adjacent where i'd like it be. What am I doing wrong?

```
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:NewTensor} 
    \sigma_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix} 
    -p + \tau_{xx} &\tau_{yx} & \tau_{zx}\\
    \tau_{xy}& -p + \tau_{yy} & \tau_{zy}\\
   \tau_{xz} & \tau_{yz} & -p + \tau_{zz}
    \end{bmatrix}

\end{equation}
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! If there is an empty line in the `equation` environment, you should also get error messages. If removing the empty line does not fix the problem, it might be that the text width of your document is too small. Hard to tell since you only post a fragment.

Answer (score 1):

In this form

```
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:NewTensor}
    \sigma_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix}
    -p + \tau_{xx} &\tau_{yx} & \tau_{zx}\\
    \tau_{xy}& -p + \tau_{yy} & \tau_{zy}\\
   \tau_{xz} & \tau_{yz} & -p + \tau_{zz}
    \end{bmatrix}

\end{equation}
```

processing LaTeX takes into account the blank space line which is located between `\end{bmatrix}` and `\end{equation}` and provides errors due to this space. When that space is removed so are the errors and the equation is formatted properly, like

```
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:NewTensor}
    \sigma_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix}
    -p + \tau_{xx} &\tau_{yx} & \tau_{zx}\\
    \tau_{xy}& -p + \tau_{yy} & \tau_{zy}\\
   \tau_{xz} & \tau_{yz} & -p + \tau_{zz}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```